# Is it possible or advisable to split mvc routes from startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

As much as I'm really enjoying the new direction that mvc core is going, one thing I feel like has gone a step back is setting up routes. An application I'm building has upwards of 50 different routes, and putting all of those routes in startup.cs seems like it will become a bit unwieldy at some point due to all of the routes.

Is it at all possible to split the routes into their own object, or middleware as was with previous versions of mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes can be defined on each controller directly, using annotations:

```
namespace Example.WebApp
{
    [Route("api/sheep")]
    public class SheepController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(long id)
        {
            return new ObjectResult("Example"+id);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]ComplexObject obj)
        {
        }
        [HttpGet("horse/{id}/{chicken}")]
        public void AnotherGet(long id, string chicken)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Using these annotations, you can build up arbitrarily complex URI schemes without all that complexity being in the Startup.cs - however, the downside is that you need to take responsibility for ensuring you don't create conflicting URIs across multiple controllers.

Comment: This is pretty slick, much better than in mvc1-5, but can you also create complex routes like this or would you have to fall back to the startup.cs?

Comment: @Marqueone what do you mean by "complex routes"? Can you give an example?